# AngularJS - Unit testing factories with complex internal logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for my angularjs application at the moment, and wanted some advice on how to test my factories. Unfortunately since I've written all of the code before writing the tests, I've got some quite complex logic in my factories.

At the moment, for example, I've got an httpRequest service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('httpRequest', ['$http',
        function($http) {
            function constructHttpRequest() {/*code*/}
            function constructCertainTypeOfHttpRequest() {/*code*/}
            function constructOtherTypeOfHttpRequest() {/*code*/}

            return {
                method1: function() {/*code*/}
                method2: function() {/*code*/}
                method3: function() {/*code*/}
            }
        }]);
```

The service exposes a lot of different request methods, which use the rather complex `construct...` functions (which are not exposed) to generate requests.

Ideally I would test all of the `construct...` functions and then test that the methods call these functions with the correct parameters; I really don't want to have to copy and paste tests for the `construct...` logic.

My question is - is there any neat way to expose these functions for the sake of testing, but not expose them to the whole application? In the ideal world, how should I write the factory code; should I place the `construct...` functions into a separate service and just make a mental note not to ever access them directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating the logic in your construct in different services, then dependency inject those services into your `httpRequest` service? This would allow you to write the test once for the injected services and not re-write them for every construct function. Also, have a look at the [$resourceProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). The `$resourceProvider` usually covers everything you need if you're building something based on a RESTful API. Hope it helps.